# ASP.NET not seeing RAM Upgrade?

Tags: memory, asp.net

For several years we've hosted an ASP.NET 4.5 application on the same VM as a SQL Server 2008R2 database in 4GB of RAM. Performance was good.

Our application is a catalog and we use .NET memory cache heavily to build up a 'working set' of parts and related data. 80,000-90,000 cache entries is typical.

Over the past weekend we upgraded to 8GB of RAM and we're seeing odd memory behavior with the ASP.NET application.

After the upgrade, Task Manager tells us that we're only using 60% of the RAM. SQL is very responsive. But cache entries grow to 15,000 and then get trimmed back to 7-8,000 range. There is lots of GC activity. It's as if the ASP.NET application is under memory pressure, and yet there's another 3+ GB of unused RAM out there.

Why would this be? Everything is 64bit. Nothing else has changed. There are no memory limits set on SQL or the Application Pool. The application is not recycling, just trimming cache very aggressively. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you manage to host a asp.net 4.5 application "several years"? I mean, it is now October 2013. ASP.NET 4.5 was released 15th of August - 2012. That means even hsoting it during go live - let's say 6 months more - you dont even have 2 years. English does not really define "several years" as "not even 2". Care to enlighten?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. The application has been 4.5 since the first of this year. It was first deployed as an ASP.NET 1.1 application on SQL Server 2000 back in 2004. We have upgraded SQL and .NET throughout the years, but the ram has always been 4GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out SQL was hogging a lot more memory than I thought it was. Before when the machine had just 4GB I let SQL run with the default min- and max-memory settings. It ran just fine for two+ years. After upgrading to 8GB RAM it gobbled it all up and ASP.NET WAS starved. I set max-memory to 5GB last night and things are nice and quiet this morning. I don't want to jinx it, but i think task manager's memory reporting lies like a friggin' rug! I am going to diddle with the 5GB over the next few days looking for the sweet spot.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SASp.NET process is 32 bit as per microsoft recommendation, even on 64 bit hosts. Do not use 64 bit witout good reason - it has disadvantages. if you need to - change the setting. Web farm setups - multiple runnning processes - are preferred.

Comment: Thanks TomTom! Could you direct me to the docs? I didn't understand that to be the case. Even so, it still seems to be under memory pressure with lots of RAM to spare - 32 or 64 bit!

Comment: @n8wrl Under 32-bit, an application is limited to ~2 GB of RAM per process. Even under 64-bit, single processes can't exceed 4 GB (going from memory on that one).

Comment: Zes. MS advice is to keep a worker procdess 32 bit and use an external cache if you have to. use webfarms & multiple processes  for higher load. The concept is sound 99% of the time. Check http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/32-bit-mode-worker-processes for more information. 32 bit apps generallz are more performance - a little. Plus most programs do not need more. Databases - ses. But things like word still are 32 bit. For example, I doubt your cache is as good as it should be and in general would write a cache component as widows service, not use iis.

Answer (score 1):

GC Activity doesn't always relate directly to how much memory you've got, but can be affected by whether the app pool is running in 32 bit or 64 bit ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/04/17/how-does-the-gc-work-and-what-are-the-sizes-of-the-different-generations.aspx)). If you're doing lots of object allocations then you'll have lots of GC activity.

We run all of our processes in 64-bit (as some of our data processing takes our process up to 12gb of RAM) and don't have an issue with it or notice the performance being any slower. It's true that all of your memory references now take up twice as much memory, but this can be at the expense of running fewer garbage collections so you should never trust any rules that say "this is always the best thing to do". In the case of performance you always want to measure things yourself.

By default, since IIS 7 the AppPools have been set to run in 64 bit. Instructions on checking/modifying your AppPool to run in 64 bit can be found here (under Advanced App Pool Settings):

[image: App Pool Settings]

Regarding caching, have you considered using an out-of-process cache, such as [Windows Server Appfabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) so that they are available across hosts and don't depend on your IIS App Pool? Your website will most likely have less GC issues if the memory pressures are located in a dedicated application.

Comment: Our AppPool is configured the same way. Still digging...